# rbenv install hangs at ruby-build: using readline from homebrew?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

```
ET-C02YQH25LVCF:sc-returns aditya.verma$ rbenv install   2.0.0-p648
Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p648.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p648.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p648...

WARNING: ruby-2.0.0-p648 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
```

Thats it, it just hangs there for eternity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 2.0.0
```

This worked for me, posting the answer so that one in future could save some time.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Could you also maybe add an explanation of what this is doing or link to where you found it, please?

Answer (score 6):

I thought it had stuck when in fact I had to wait just a little bit. The process shows no sign of any activity and my CPU was not very busy for quite some time. Get a coffee before searching for a solution, installation took almost 5 minutes in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I let my machine run for about 15 minutes and it eventually completed.

I found out that the [Readline library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) is a command line editor by GNU.
The Build Errors analytics on [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/readline) are also pretty encouraging so I'd advise people to let it run.

I'm not sure what rbenv was using it for but I believe we should just let it do it's job.

Answer (score 1):

If you trail the log, like it mentions at the top as you're installing. You'll see it is doing work in the background. It just takes time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33849114)

Comment: I disagree with your point that this does not answer the question, but you are the moderator.

Comment: The most-voted answer looks like an answer. This one looks like a comment. That is why you see this message. "It just takes time" does not really answer anything, as it might be an issue or it might not. Anything that has duality behind is questionable.

Comment: Don't get offended, most of the answers here are not really answers, but rather comments. Hunting for reputation. Only one answer here provides an exact step of what could be done to answer the question (and it is the OP who answered).

Comment: I'm providing them the steps to see in the logs exactly what is happening and when they are thinking it hangs, that it is actually running tasks in the background.